# how to call user control from another user control in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, telerik

I have one problem for calling user control from another user control my code like this :

```
 public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
}

        private void commandBarButtonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            UserControl2 usr2 = new UserControl2();
            this.Hide();
            this.Parent.Controls.Add(usr2);
}
```

it is returning this error :

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: not it is different from our question

Comment: How is that different? You get a NullRefenreceException. Something Is Null. I'm guessing `this.Parent`. Debug, find what is null, and fix it. Simple.

Comment: I cannot debug because it is dll it using from another application.

Comment: [how to debug a dll c#](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=how+to+debug+a+dll+c%23&rlz=1C1LENP_iwIL718IL718&oq=how+to+debug+a+dll&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.9263j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I done like this but I have error : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/calling-another-user-control-from-one1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not trying to add a control to the parent (maybe Form1) but you are trying to add the UserControl2 as parent of UserControl1. That is not possible.

Quick and dirty would be something like this:

```
        UserControl2 usr2 = new UserControl2 ();
        this.Hide();
        Form1 parentForm = (this.Parent as Form1);

        parentForm.Controls.Add(new usr2());
```

Comment: I cannot use Form.I have to use only user controls on my application.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/calling-another-user-control-from-one1  I done like this

Comment: @SezerErdogan what does your hierarchy look like? Which Control is the parent of which?

Comment: UserControl1 is my parent control

Comment: @SezerErdogan And you want to add Control2 to Control1? Then use this.Controls.Add(usr2);

Comment: Yes I want to call another usercontrol2 in usercontrol1

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing controls with `x:Name`, and access them with the specified name if they are in the same XAML file.
Edit: Also, if you're getting a `NullReferenceException`, the problem lies within you calling a method on a `NULL` object.

Answer (score 0):

`this.Parent` is null, a basic `form` has no parent, but `panel`, for example, may have `Parent property.

Also, if you wanted to do something like `this.Controls.Add(usr2);` you will get `System.ArgumentException` because of you cant add form to another form (without any containers)

Comment: I done like this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/calling-another-user-control-from-one1

Comment: @SezerErdogan what is `windowsFormsControlLibrary` ?